# Do it yourself or use a commercial CDN

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn

Consider a dynamic content html web site with lots of static .js and image baggage must be hosted in a single location. The site will soon have a few 1000 new users clustered in a single country on the other side of the world. This new remote country has a Amazon S3 node and all users in that country will be within 1000Km of the S3 node.

To improve the user expperience in the remote country I propose to locate the largest and most referenced static files on a local server close to that remote user community and rewrite URLs when servicing those users.

My feeling is that using a commercial CDN would be overkill in this situation and directly referencing our own manually managed S3 static content would give us more control particularly for occasional urgent patches to JavaScript.

Comment: "This new remote country has a Google S3 node..." - I think you mean Amazon S3?

Comment: @geoff - Yes I did, now corrected thanks. Just prior to posting my question I had been reading up on which standard .js frameworks are loaded in the Google CDN for free public access and so had google on the brain. Unfortunatly my App's JS framework predates Ext.JS and JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store your static content, it makes sense to use Amazon's [CloudFront CDN](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

You can start using it and get all the benefits of the CDN without too much effort.

Comment: What I am debating here is whether CloudFront brings anything extra given that the user population is already clustered around a single Amazon S3 node. CDNs bring update propagation delays and loss of control over who can hit my site's static content. With S3 and a registered population of users I can put some access controls in place to limit access to the IP in our JavaScript. (I should add this is a benefit that has occured to me since posting the orginal question)

Comment: @camelCase - I agree thats its simpler to work with directly with S3 rather than cloudfront although there are trade offs to both approches. With S3 you'll be responsible for replication, url rewriting etc. With CloudFront all that is taken care of for you. BTW, you can still use CloudFront and protect your content. See http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2009/11/new-amazon-cloudfront-feature-private-content.html for more info